# Bootstrap modal sometimes showing and other times not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have several Modals on the same page, but they are only showing intermittently. The Models are trigged by this script.

```
$(".embed").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetModal = $(this).data('target');
    $(targetModal).modal("show");
})
```

HTML is

```
<div class="embed" data-target="#embed0">
    <img src="images/stakeholder-interest.png"  alt="Analyse stakeholder interest"/> 
</div>
```

Modal html is

```
<div id="embed0" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;  </button>
            </div><!--END model-header-->
            <div class="modal-body">        
            </div><!--END model-body-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end modal-content-->
    </div><!-- end modal-dialog-->
</div><!-- END embed0 1st image-->
```

Comment: Note that you are missing the closing tag of `<div id="embed0"...`

Comment: thanks missed that in the question. The code is on the page. Will edit the question.

Comment: ok trying on experts-exchange. Not finding stackoverflow the help it once was.

Answer (score 0):

SumoMe Highlighter is the culprit. Turning the Highlighter off allowed the modals to be shown on every image, correctly and consistently. Suspect SumoMe CSS which is applied on page load is intefering with other page elements.